# Error 403 when trying to upload file to google drive via python

Tags: python, upload

So I'm new to python (and this is a first post to stack overflow).  I'm trying to use python to upload and download files to and from a google drive account (and eventually reference files from this drive on a customized work tiki wiki).  The code below is from google's python api resources.  It will successfully list the files on my drive (as it should).  However, when I attempt to upload a file (see 10th line from bottom) I am given the following error:

```
An error occured: <HttpError 403 "Insufficient Permission">
```

I've been looking around for a few hours now and I can't figure out how to get around this.  I'm thinking I need to request some sort of token.  Not really sure.  Again, I'm new to this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import httplib2
import os

from apiclient import discovery
import oauth2client
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Drive API Quickstart'


def get_credentials():
    """Gets valid user credentials from storage.

    If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
    the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

    Returns:
        Credentials, the obtained credential.
    """
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                   'drive-quickstart.json')

    store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: # Needed only for compatability with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print 'Storing credentials to ' + credential_path
    return credentials

from apiclient import errors
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
# ...

def insert_file(service, title, description, parent_id, mime_type, filename):
  """Insert new file.

  Args:
    service: Drive API service instance.
    title: Title of the file to insert, including the extension.
    description: Description of the file to insert.
    parent_id: Parent folder's ID.
    mime_type: MIME type of the file to insert.
    filename: Filename of the file to insert.
  Returns:
    Inserted file metadata if successful, None otherwise.
  """
  media_body = MediaFileUpload(filename, mimetype=mime_type, resumable=True)
  body = {
    'title': title,
    'description': description,
    'mimeType': mime_type
  }
  # Set the parent folder.
  if parent_id:
    body['parents'] = [{'id': parent_id}]

  try:
    file = service.files().insert(
        body=body,
        media_body=media_body).execute()

    # Uncomment the following line to print the File ID
    # print 'File ID: %s' % file['id']

    return file
  except errors.HttpError, error:
    print 'An error occured: %s' % error
    return None

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Google Drive API.

    Creates a Google Drive API service object and outputs the names and IDs
    for up to 10 files.
    """
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('drive', 'v2', http=http)

    insert_file(service, 'picture.jpg', 'no_description', False, 'image/jpeg', '/Users/ethankay/Documents/Work/Current_Work/Astrophysics/Code/Logger_Program/Master/TestUploadFiles/test3.jpg')

    results = service.files().list(maxResults=10).execute()
    items = results.get('items', [])
    if not items:
        print 'No files found.'
    else:
        print 'Files:'
        for item in items:
            print '{0} ({1})'.format(item['title'], item['id'])




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

your Google Drive scope is

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'

which has no permission to upload files. You need to change it to

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'

to be able to manage files. Try to re-authenticate with your Google API project.

Answer (score -1):

1. Save this code as quickstart.py
2. Run it from command line using sudo. [ sudo python quickstart.py ]
3. Use your Windows Password
4. The quickstart.py will attempt to open a new window or tab in your default browser. If this fails, copy the URL from the console and manually open it in your browser.
5. Click the Accept button
6. DONE